# relation between Riemann and Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis

if $f$ is a differentiable function, and $f'$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, I'm asked to prove
$$\int_0^1 f'(x)\,dx=f(1)-f(0)$$
in Lebesgue sense.

First I want to ask whether $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable. There is a well-known counterexample that $f'$ is not Lebesgue integrable but Riemann integrable improperly, but $f'$ is unbounded in that case, what can we say if $f'$ is bounded? Is the discontinuous point be a 0-measure set?

thanks!

Comment: It is measurable since it is the pointwise limit of measurable functions and since $f'$ is bounded, it follows that it is integrable.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, it makes sense.

Comment: $f'$ is clearly integrable, since $g_n(x)=n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))\to f'(x)$ and $f'$ is bounded. But is the value of the integral expressable as $f(1)-f(0)$? Doesn't $f$ have to be absolutely contiunuous? I'm thinking of the Cantor Function as a counterexample.

Comment: Perhaps I'm taking a naive approach to this, but it would seem to me that the question hinges on proving that $f$ is $AC[0,1]$. @Chilango, the Cantor Function doesn't strike me as a counterexample, since $f$ being differentiable and $f'$ bounded on $[0,1]$ would imply that $f$ is differentiable at every point in $[0,1]$, while the Cantor Function is only differentiable a.e. on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @NicholasStull: Quite right. I was (wrongly) assuming only a.e. differentiability for f in the first place. Thanks. In the case of differentiability everywhere, f is clearly AC on [0,1].

Comment: @Chilango, since $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'$ is bounded everywhere, then it is indeed immediate that $f\in AC[0,1]$ (though if this is HW, one should write a short argument why), in which case the statement follows from FTOC.